# What's wrong with gVim copy paste between windows?

Tags: vim

I'm new to vim and I'm using gVim on Windows. I have two windows open in the same gvim instance and I'm just trying to copy some code from one to another. For some reason when it pastes it replaces the contents of some code with literally this:

```
list.forEach(function(name){...}------------------------------------------
```

Obviously, my real code does not have ... or a ton of dashes. What the hell is happening?

Comment: Exactly what procedure are you using to copy code (gVim supports at least a couple of methods)? What does the original selection look like?

Comment: Ah this is infuriating just happened again. I am just using visual mode to select the text and pushing y, then going into the other window and pushing p.

Comment: I just found out if I navigate with the keyboard into that area, it 'opens' up and I can see the code that was hidden inside. I must be somehow folding the code.

Comment: Congratulations, you just discovered folding. See `:help folding`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dashes (`----------`) give it away: The block of code has been folded. (You probably also see the line with different colors (depending on your colorscheme).) Depending on the *filetype*, folding can be manual or automatic. For your (JavaScript?) code, it's the latter. So when you paste a block of code, Vim automatically detects the block and folds it.

There's a whole lot of commands and options around folding. Read more about it at `:help folding`. If you find this too confusing (for now), turn it off via

```
:set nofoldenable
```

Answer (score 0):

Just press `zo` on the dashes(-----)

Aside: Use `zf` on selected (`v`) lines to fold lines.

```
zo - Open
zo - Fold
```